# FFMPEG output filename being read from a text file

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

So I'm using recover_mp4 in conjunction with ffmpeg to rebuild corrupted video files from a SD card.  I have 300+ files so I'm trying to automate the process.
I threw together a batch file as the quickest example.  The "var" variable is passed successfully in the first two commands, however, FFMPEG doesn't seem to accept it.  I'd like FFMPEG to create the fixed output files using the textfile name + rec (badfile1-rec.mp4)

Am I just missing a setting with FFMPEG?
This is my batch file:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (bad-videos.txt) do set var=%%a&call :process
:process
    call ""c:\recover\bin\recover_mp4.exe good.mp4 --analyze""
    timeout 5
    call ""c:\recover\bin\recover_mp4.exe %var% recovered.h264 recovered.aac""
    timeout 5
    call ""c:\recover\bin\ffmpeg.exe -r 30 -i recovered.h264 -i recovered.aac -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -c:v copy -c:a copy %var%-rec.mp4""
    timeout 60
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

I just glanced at your script. Try this:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (bad-videos.txt) do set var=%%a&call :process
goto :eof
:process
    call ""c:\recover\bin\recover_mp4.exe good.mp4 --analyze""
    timeout 5
    call ""c:\recover\bin\recover_mp4.exe %var% recovered.h264 recovered.aac""
    timeout 5
    call ""c:\recover\bin\ffmpeg.exe -r 30 -i recovered.h264 -i recovered.aac -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -c:v copy -c:a copy %var%-rec.mp4""
    timeout 60
goto :eof
```